# Overloading operator < with const, but don't insert into map as const

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I'm having an issue. I have a class with an overloaded operator like this..

```
class Foo
{
        friend bool operator<(const Foo &a, const Foo &b);
        ...
};

bool operator<(const Foo &a, const Foo &b)
{
        return a.member < b.member;
}
```

Then in a function in a class that holds some Foos in a map as keys...

```
void Bar::Update()
{
        for (FooItr itr = foos.begin(); itr != foos.end();) {
                FooItr test = itr++;
                if (!test->first.Check()) { // Check() is const
                        my_map.insert(*test);
                        foos.remove(test);
                }
        }

        for (MapItr itr = my_map.begin(); itr != my_map.end(); ++itr) {
                itr->first.Update(); // Update is not const
        }
}
```

and I get an error message like...

`error: passing ‘const Foo’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Foo::Update()’ discards qualifiers`

I believe the reason is that the my_map.insert() is inserting const Foos, but I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys in a `map` are always `const`, even if you don't say so. It's like that to prevent programming errors.

Consider what would happen if `Update` changed `member` - the map data structure would be based on the original ordering, but now that `member` has changed, that ordering could be wrong! The map would be completely broken - you wouldn't be able to find, insert or remove data correctly.

---

So, some options to fix this are:

- Use a different data structure, where it doesn't matter if the objects get "out of order", such as `vector`.
- Move the data that gets updated somewhere else. Sometimes it really belongs in the `mapped_type` (`map`'s second template parameter). Sometimes you can define a new `struct` to store the current `mapped_type`, and the data that needs to change.
- If you were changing something that doesn't affect the type's observable state, like a cache, then I might suggest making the changed data members `mutable` and making the relevant member functions `const`, or storing the mutable data in a `scoped_ptr`. However, a function named `Update` suggests that the data being updated is fundamental to the type.

Comment: Well the full context of the problem isn't there, but using a multimap solved it (by avoiding the issue entirely, again won't go into it). Good possible solutions though.